# Extract data from website using TEdgeBrowser Delphi 10.4

Tags: parsing, delphi, tedgebrowser

I would like to know how to extract some data from this website

https://estrelabet.com/ptb/games/detail/casino/demo/7787

It is a game.

I need to extract the last coeficient of each round, and the total of bets to feed a table.

For example:
Total Bets: 2100
Payout coeficient: 2.35

I need to save 2100 and 2.35 in my table.

I am trying to do a data analisys about the game statistics.

I am using Delphi 10.4 and loading the game using TEdgeBrowser.

Thank You

Comment: Use a component like ``TIdHttp`` for this job.